# Can I use GetObjectById for 2 IDs?

Tags: java

I'm working on a project. And I need to get an Object based on 2 IDs that it contains. How can I retrieve the object by using getObjectById. It allows only one Id from a class.'

Comment: Are you sure, that it's 2 IDs it contain and not two different variables?

Comment: Iam storing 2 IDs of other 2 tables in this table, So they became variables  though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I needed something like this, I used 2 `Map` objects to have a quick indexes for both fields. When adding objects, I simply updated both `Map`s with them and corresponding IDs.

Comment: Haven't tried it. Map approach turned out to be fastest for me.

Comment: Can you show a sample code? I tried with setFilter . It worked But I have some issues in Queries.

Comment: Post your code here, so that I can modify it for use with `Map`s. Otherwise it's hundreds of strings, irrelevant to your matter.